# If power is lost while a file is being read in read-only mode, can that file's data be lost?

Tags: python, file, file-io

If power is lost while a file is being read in read-only mode, can that file's data be lost?

Example in Python:

```
>>> f = open("example.txt", "r")
>>> first_line = f.readline()
>>> second_line = f.readline()
>>> # Here the machine executing the above code unexpectedly powers off.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If power is lost while a file is being read in read-only mode, can that file's data be lost?

One would think that since you have the file open in read-only mode, the answer would be a solid "no". There's two scenarios that come to mind:

### Hardware failure

In the case of a hard disk, the head must be above the platter to read the file. If the power dies, that could be just the last straw that causes the disk to just fail outright.

### Access times

**File metadata**. Even when opening a file read-only, "last access date" might still need to get updated, and *thus cause a write*. Whether this is true depends; consider:

- does the filesystem that the file exists on support a last access time?
- Is the filesystem configured to use it? (Linux, for example, has a `noatime` attribute that means access times are not updated)
- Is the filesystem read-only? (again, Linux is a good example here; you can mount an FS as read-only)

If there is an access time that could be written, the next big question is *does the FS at hand journal metadata*? A "journal" is a data structure many FSs use to prevent corruption. If the answer is "no", then I'd say "yes, it is possible."

Corrupting the file metadata, could, conceivably, render the data in the file itself corrupt. (More likely, the metadata that stores where on disk the file is located is likely near where the access time; this might cause that data to itself get corrupt. The file contents are probably fine, but the thing that says where they are is what got corrupt.)

At the end of the day, if you need to protect against such things,

1. Use a filesystem that journals metadata. (`ext3`, for example, can do this.) Do note that some FSs with journals *do not* journal metadata. (They journal only the main file data.) (Also note that some are configurable either way.)
2. Always have a backup. The disk can always outright fail.

Answer (score 2):

Your file's data *should* be safe, but you should be aware that some file systems will modify the [access time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29#Criticism_of_atime) in the file's meta-data, even if you're just reading the file, and even if the partition is mounted read-only. However, if you are worried about that it's possible to disable that feature - on Unix-like systems you can mount the partition with the `noatime` option. Please see the man pages for `mount` and `fstab` for  details.

But there's really no need to be too concerned about this if you are using a modern [journaling file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system).